# What C# database support multi connections over shared network?

Tags: c#, database

I want to build a simple database program in C# to add,update and remove information.
The program should be on shared network between 3-5 computers and each could add his information in the same time.

I searched and found that SQLite isn't good for that, and don't know what will be.

I'm looking for some simple database, not something that I should install in each PC to support it.

There isn't an access to the internet, its blocked except a few websites so its not possible to use MSSQL or mySQL.

Thank you.

Comment: If each machine is hitting the same database, you only need to install one database server.

Comment: Pretty much every database provider out there will support multiple connections over a shared network. That's half the usefulness of a database. Also, C# can be used to access almost any of them, and any of them can be accessed with other languages as well.

Comment: Exactly, phil. The question is akin to "which car can be used to drive on a shared road".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the users don't have access to the internet doesn't mean that you can't use MySQL or MS SQL Server. You can install MySQL on one of the computers (the one that will play the server role) and have all the other computers connect to the MySQL instance installed on the local server since you say that they will be on an internal network.

As far as Databases go, there are plenty you can use: MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc... Just don't use MsAccess. ;)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your quick reply! Why don't use Access? Also, If I'll install MSSQL or MYSQL, I will need a static internal IP, right? There is an other option from installing DB on my PC? Thanks.

Comment: @user926249 Yes, you will need a static internal ip but only for the computer that will host the database but that shouldn't concern you either since even the $25-dollar routers have options for address reservation based on the MAC Address. Don't use Access because is not intended for concurrent users. You will run into issues almost surely.

Comment: Ok, I understand. The problem is the network is in my work, so i'm not the admin and don't have admin permissions to install programs on my PC. That's why i'm looking for simple database option to put it on the network so all PC could get access to it without any problems. I'll try to check and see if its possible to unblock my server IP to use MSSQL db for it. If there is another solution, I'll be happy to hear. Thank you very much!